# Creating a dynamic javascript countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, webmatrix

I'm looking to create a dynamic javascript countdown timer, I want to pass it a datetime variable from my SQL server database and have it count down to this date then display a message, I've tried nearly every JQuery plugin I can find and Havent been able to edit them to do what I need, I also need to be able to have multiple countdown timers on the same page,

Any help would be much appriciated

Cheers

Scott

=======EDIT=======

After much Trial and Error I was able to modify this js http://andrewu.co.uk/clj/countdown/pro/

to do what I needed

Comment: If you want somebody to just write this for you, you're going to have to provide more detailed requirements and establish a payment scheme. If you're having issues with one of the approaches you've tried, you should probably post the code that's at issue.

Comment: Yeah, that would have been a better approach, I kinda wrote this as I was leaving work, On the plus side after much trial and error I managed to modify this http://andrewu.co.uk/clj/countdown/pro/ to do what I needed

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is the preferred way of dealing with situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function Thick(startin) {
  startin--;
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = startin;
  if(startin > 0) setTimeout('Thick(' + startin + ')', 1000);
}
```

call thus function in body onLoad like:

```
<body onLoad="Thick(20);">
```

hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//TODAY'S DATE
$today = time();
//FETCHES DATE AND TIME FOR THE EVENT FROM DATABASE

$sql = "SELECT * FROM post";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$Row = (mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
$th = $Row['endtime'];    
}
echo $th

first of all put it into a variable then use your javascript to call the variable

//let get todays date here
var today = new Date();
var DD = today.getDate();
var MM = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var YYYY = today.getFullYear();
//let get the Difference in Sec btw the two dates
var _DateFromDBProgEndDate = '<?php echo $th; ?>';
var ProgEndTime = new Date(_DateFromDBProgEndDate);
var TodayTime = new Date();

var differenceTravel = ProgEndTime.getTime()- TodayTime.getTime() ;
var seconds = Math.floor((differenceTravel) / (1000));
////////////////////////////////
var SecDiffFromToday = seconds;
var seconds = SecDiffFromToday;
function timer() {
    var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
    var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
    var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
    var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
    var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Completed";
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}
var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
</script>


the  javascript call in the variable with  '<?php echo $th; ?>'; then the javascript does the count down with out refreshing the page
```